# How to Properly Style List Item with Icon and Title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a li (list item) which contains four elements. 2 of the elements I would like to align to left and the other 2 to the right. The li is part of a page using the Bootstrap framework and FontAwesome project: http://pctechtips.org/apps/todo/
Here's the li

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
 <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pay Car Insurance
 <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li class="list-group-item  justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o left" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <span class="left marg_left">Pay Car Insurance </span>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil right marg_left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o right  " aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

in css ::

```
.marg_left {
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
     float: left;
}

.marg_right{
     margin-right:12px;
}
```

[image: I this what u wanted ??]

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you need to do in your case (to make it work with native **Bootstrap 4** classes only and without any css hacking) is to add the `ml-auto` (margin-left:auto) class to the third element i.e. the pencil icon.

Then you just add a bit of padding to the plus and the pencil icon by adding the `pr-3` (padding-right) class to both. That's it!

Here's the working code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="add-item text-center col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
            <h1 class="heading-4">Todo List Items</h1>
            <ul id="list" class="list-group mt-4 pb-4">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>Pay Car Insurance
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil ml-auto pr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to turn those icons into links, you'll need to add the `ml-auto` class to the anchor like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="add-item text-center col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
            <h1 class="heading-4">Todo List Items</h1>
            <ul id="list" class="list-group mt-4 pb-4">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>Pay Car Insurance
                    <a href="#" class="ml-auto pr-3"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try add `class="pull-right"` or `class="pull-left"`

Comment: this is for large screen size only